# Expactation of piecewise function $g(x)$ given only CDF of $x$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Given $$g(x)=\begin{cases}
x-c, & x>c\\
x, & x\le c
\end{cases}$$
where $x$ is a non-negative random variable, $c$ is a non-negetive constant, and $\mathrm{P}(x>C)$ is known ($C$ can be any non-negative constant). $\mathrm{P}(x>C)=\mathrm{P}(x\ge C)$, so CDF $F(C)$ is known.

How to get $\mathrm{E}(g(x))$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
E(g(x))
&= \int g(x)\,dP = \int_{x>c}(x-c)\,dP + \int_{x\le c}x\,dP\\
&= \int x\,dP - \int_{x>c}c\,dP = E(x) - cP(x>c).
\end{align*}
So, also $E(x)$ should be known to obtain $E(g(x))$.